# Warning - Attempt to present UIAlertController on VC

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertcontroller

The first time my app starts, I have a user registration screen where I capture name and email. 
As part of text field validation, I display a `UIAlertController` if the validation fails. This validation method is called inside my Save button action and `UIAlertController` is displayed here as well.

This was working fine when I had turned off Size Classes for my project. I have now updated my project to use Size Classes. Since then I have been getting this warning.

```
Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x7b074660> on <WelcomeViewController: 0x7b0428d0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

So now, if I click on Save it moves to the next screen without displaying an alert.

Here is the code for what I described above:

```
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {

NSString *errorMessage = [self validateForm];

if (errorMessage) {
    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Detail Missing" message:errorMessage preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {}];

    [alert addAction:cancelAction];

    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

    return;
}

//Saving username and email in NSUSerDefaults
NSUserDefaults *userData = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userData setObject:self.userTextField.text forKey:@"UserName"];
[userData setObject:self.emailTextField.text forKey:@"Email"];
[userData setBool:YES forKey:@"UserReg"]; }


- (NSString *)validateForm {
    NSString *errorMessage;

    if (![self.userTextField.text isValidText]){
        errorMessage = @"Please enter your name";
    } else if (![self.emailTextField.text isValidEmail]){
        errorMessage = @"Please enter a valid email address";
    }

    return errorMessage;
}
```

In `AppDelegate.m` I perform a check if user information has been stored or not. If it hasn't been, my welcome screen is shown (where i capture details) else I load the main app screen. 
If I enter user details correctly the first time and press save, the app functions normally without any problem.

I have gone through answers for a similar problem, unfortunately they did not help me as my UIAlertController is called in the save button action rather than `viewDidLoad` or `viewDidAppear` or `viewWillAppear`.

What can I do to solve this issue?

**Additional Information for Rob's response**

I've tried both approaches suggested by Rob - one where I just look for the view controller's view address and other where I subclass UIView and assign a tag to the root view of WelcomeViewController. Both results are similar, in that I can find my view in the hierarchy.

Here are results with using subclass and tag:

```
    <WelcomeViewController 0x78ea7850>, state: appeared, view: <WelcomeView 0x78e7b210>
   + <UINavigationController 0x78e58c00>, state: disappeared, view: <UILayoutContainerView 0x78e5bcb0> not in the window, presented with: <_UIFullscreenPresentationController 0x78ef3ac0>
   |    | <WardrobeListTableViewController 0x78ef3940>, state: disappeared, view: <UITableView 0x7a357600> not in the window
```

Recursive Hierarchy

```
<UIWindow: 0x799ad460; frame = (0 0; 320 568); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x799adac0>; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x799acfe0>>
   | <WelcomeView: 0x78e7b210; frame = (0 0; 320 568); autoresize = W+H; tag = 10; layer = <CALayer: 0x78e7b0c0>>
   |    | <UINavigationBar: 0x78e7aed0; frame = (0 20; 320 44); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x78e6fb60>; layer = <CALayer: 0x78e7ade0>>
   |    |    | <_UINavigationBarBackground: 0x78e70bd0; frame = (0 0; 320 44); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x78e70d90>>
   |    |    |    | <_UIBackdropView: 0x78e5df70; frame = (0 0; 320 44); opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UIBackdropViewLayer: 0x78e59050>>
   |    |    |    |    | <_UIBackdropEffectView: 0x78e58620; frame = (0 0; 320 44); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; userInteractionEnabled = NO; animations = { filters.colorMatrix.inputColorMatrix=<CABasicAnimation: 0x799b3730>; }; layer = <CABackdropLayer: 0x78e582b0>>
   |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x78e57b40; frame = (0 0; 320 44); hidden = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x78e57b10>>
   |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x78e706b0; frame = (0 44; 320 0.5); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x78e70580>>
   |    |    | <UINavigationItemView: 0x78e74390; frame = (91.5 8; 137 27); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x78e74260>>
   |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x78e74060; frame = (0 3.5; 137 21.5); text = 'User Registration'; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x78e73f30>>
   |    |    | <_UINavigationBarBackIndicatorView: 0x799b6a00; frame = (8 11.5; 13 21); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x799b6ba0>>
   |    | <UITextView: 0x79373400; frame = (0 64; 320 90); text = 'Welcome to the Baby Wardr...'; clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x78e6dfb0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x78e6fa00>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {320, 88}>
   |    |    | <<_UITextContainerView: 0x78e6c9c0; frame = (0 0; 320 88); layer = <_UITextTiledLayer: 0x78e6cca0>> minSize = {320, 0}, maxSize = {3.4028235e+38, 3.4028235e+38}, textContainer = <NSTextContainer: 0x79886290 size = (320.000000,340282346638528859811704183484516925440.000000); widthTracksTextView = YES; heightTracksTextView = NO>; exclusionPaths = 0x0; lineBreakMode = 0>
   |    |    |    | <_UITileLayer: 0x78e4fab0> (layer)
   |    |    |    | <_UITileLayer: 0x78e54860> (layer)
   |    |    |    | <_UITileLayer: 0x78e656e0> (layer)
   |    |    |    | <_UITileLayer: 0x78e5a060> (layer)
   |    |    |    | <UITextSelectionView: 0x78e63900; frame = (0 0; 0 0); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x78e637b0>>
   |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x799b7090; frame = (0 87.5; 600 2.5); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x799b7110>>
   |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x799b74e0; frame = (317.5 8; 2.5 82); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = LM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x799b7560>>
   |    | <UITextField: 0x78e7e2a0; frame = (16 174; 288 30); text = ''; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x79996a90>; layer = <CALayer: 0x78e7e3e0>>
   |    |    | <_UITextFieldRoundedRectBackgroundViewNeue: 0x78e7b600; frame = (0 0; 288 30); opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x78e7b5d0>>
   |    |    | <UITextFieldLabel: 0x78e7b820; frame = (7 1; 274 27); text = 'Name'; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x78e7b7d0>>
   |    | <UITextField: 0x78efbec0; frame = (16 214; 288 30); text = ''; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x799ae7c0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x78e7f420>>
   |    |    | <_UITextFieldRoundedRectBackgroundViewNeue: 0x78e7cea0; frame = (0 0; 288 30); opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x78e7d080>>
   |    |    | <UITextFieldLabel: 0x78e7bef0; frame = (7 1; 274 27); text = 'Email Address'; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x78e7c0f0>>
   |    | <UIButton: 0x799ae9b0; frame = (80 264; 160 30); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x799aebb0>>
   |    |    | <UIButtonLabel: 0x78e5e460; frame = (25 6; 109.5 18); text = 'Save & Proceed'; alpha = 0.2; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x78e5e0f0>>
   |    | <_UILayoutGuide: 0x78e73db0; frame = (0 0; 0 20); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x78e73e70>>
   |    | <_UILayoutGuide: 0x78e66ea0; frame = (0 568; 0 0); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x78e7cb10>>
```

Any further suggestions on how to solve this issue?

**Additional information for Kiddae**
As I mentioned, I perform a check in AppDelegate.m to decide which viewController to show. Here is the code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds];

    //Check if user data has been saved & determine the initial view controller
    NSString *identifier;
    BOOL isSaved = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"UserReg"];
    if (isSaved)
    {
        identifier=@"Wardrobe";
    }
    else
    {
        identifier=@"Welcome";
    }

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:identifier];

    self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Please show where you are displaying `WelcomeViewController`

Comment: @KIDdAe I have added more information to my question above.

Comment: The vc (view controller) hierarchy doesn't quite make sense because you should see either `WelcomeViewController` or `WardrobeListTableViewController`, _but not both._ And the fact that the vc hierarchy appears to be out of sync with the view hierarchy could start to explain the error you got when presenting the alert. The question is how did you end up with that curious vc hierarchy. I tried the code in your question, but am unable to reproduce what you describe. Are you ever doing any manual `addSubview` or `removeFromSuperview`? Just trying to figure out how to reproduce your scenario.

Comment: Another strange bit is that I've got 2 more user forms in my app, where I use the same field validation method and display UIAlertController. This works perfectly well for both the forms unlike the Welcome screen.

Comment: I agree, WardrobeListTableViewController did not make sense in the VC hierarchy. I went through my code closely again and I am not performing any manual `addSubview` or `removeFromSuperview`. I've been facing this problem since I updated my code to use Size Classes for iPhone. Could that have any impact? **Guess what, I was unable to reproduce a similar VC hierarchy that I posted earlier.** All I get now is `<WelcomeViewController 0x7b727420>, state: appeared, view: <WelcomeView 0x7b74c3c0>`

Answer (score 0):

You can get this error if your view controller hierarchy gets out of sync with your view hierarchy for any reason. Run the app and either pause execution (but don't stop it) or add breakpoint in the code. If you're running this on iOS 8 or later, at the `(lldb)` prompt, you can examine the `_printHierarchy` results like  so:

```
(lldb) po [[[UIWindow keyWindow] rootViewController] _printHierarchy]
<UINavigationController 0x7fef00d3dc10>, state: appeared, view: <UILayoutContainerView 0x7fef02b63550>
   | <myapp.ViewController 0x7fef00d348b0>, state: appeared, view: <UIView 0x7fef00e43950>
   |    | <myapp.WelcomeViewController 0x7fef02b12290>, state: appeared, view: <UIView 0x7fef02b6b520>
```

Make sure that `WelcomeViewController` appears in that view controller hierarchy.

You can also confirm the view hierarchy with `recursiveDescription`:

```
(lldb) po [[UIWindow keyWindow] recursiveDescription]
<UIWindow: 0x7fa17a83a750; frame = (0 0; 375 667); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fa17a823120>; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x7fa17a8241e0>>
   | <UILayoutContainerView: 0x7fa178527a80; frame = (0 0; 375 667); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fa178578c20>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fa178634dc0>>
   |    | <UINavigationTransitionView: 0x7fa17863b5c0; frame = (0 0; 375 667); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fa17863b6d0>>
   |    |    | <UIViewControllerWrapperView: 0x7fa178647570; frame = (0 0; 375 667); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fa178647640>>
   |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x7fa1786480d0; frame = (0 0; 375 667); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fa1786473d0>>
   |    |    |    |    | <_UILayoutGuide: 0x7fa1786481a0; frame = (0 0; 0 64); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fa1786470d0>>
   |    |    |    |    | <_UILayoutGuide: 0x7fa178648b00; frame = (0 667; 0 0); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fa178647660>>
   |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x7fef02b6b520; frame = (0 0; 375 667); autoresize = W+H; tag = 1; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fa178426c60>>
   |    |    |    |    |    | <UIButton: 0x7fa1784260b0; frame = (309 629; 46 30); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fa1784254b0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIButtonLabel: 0x7fa17842b1b0; frame = (0 6; 46 18); text = 'Button'; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7fa17842b520>>
   |    |    |    |    |    | <_UILayoutGuide: 0x7fa178426d50; frame = (0 0; 0 64); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fa178426e30>>
   |    |    |    |    |    | <_UILayoutGuide: 0x7fa178426fa0; frame = (0 667; 0 0); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fa1784255e0>>
   |    | <UINavigationBar: 0x7fa17a8309a0; frame = (0 20; 375 44); opaque = NO; autoresize = W; gestureRecognizers = ; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fa17a826020>>
   |    |    | <_UINavigationBarBackground: 0x7fa17a83a9f0; frame = (0 -20; 375 64); autoresize = W; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fa17a834ca0>>
   |    |    |    | <_UIBackdropView: 0x7fa1785796e0; frame = (0 0; 375 64); opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UIBackdropViewLayer: 0x7fa17863f2d0>>
   |    |    |    |    | <_UIBackdropEffectView: 0x7fa1786404e0; frame = (0 0; 375 64); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CABackdropLayer: 0x7fa178640bc0>>
   |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x7fa178641a30; frame = (0 0; 375 64); hidden = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fa178641b00>>
   |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x7fa17a83b0b0; frame = (0 64; 375 0.5); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fa17a825e20>>
   |    |    | <UINavigationButton: 0x7fa17a832fd0; frame = (333 8; 34 30); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fa17a8329d0>>
   |    |    |    | <UIButtonLabel: 0x7fa17a835e10; frame = (0 4; 34 20.5); text = 'Item'; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7fa17a8362c0>>
   |    |    | <_UINavigationBarBackIndicatorView: 0x7fa178638f90; frame = (8 11.5; 13 21); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fa1786392d0>>
```

This view hierarchy is sometimes hard to follow, so you might want to either:

- Specify a non-zero `tag` for the root `view` of your `WelcomeViewController` (because `recursiveDescription` will show non-zero tag numbers). This is what I did above (and I highlighted the line so you can quickly see it, something that lldb obviously won't do for you).
- Subclass `UIView` and specify that as the base class for the view of `WelcomeViewController` (note, this `UIView` subclass doesn't have to do anything, we just want a different class so you can differentiate it in the `recursiveDescription` output). Or,
- Identify the view controller's view address (`0x7fef02b6b520` in my example) from the view controller hierarchy, and look for that view in the view hierarchy.

Any of these techniques can help you identify if your particular view controller's view is within the hierarchy.

Comment: I've updated my question to include the output on running the lldb prompts you suggested.